# Adding setState inside firebase .set() function of firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

This is my  function that needs to be sorted out. Everytime, I call this.setState({}) inside function(error), it gives error saying, Objects are not valid as react child.

```
saveDatabase(userID)
  {
     firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
     email: this.state.email,
     password: this.state.password
     }, function(error) {
       if (error) {
          console.warn(error);
         // this.setState({
         //   error : error,
         //   isLoading: false
         // })
       }
       else {
         Actions.main_home()
       }
     });
  }
```

Comment: It's probably because you are trying to render the `error` object as is instead of displaying an error message or something. Check the function that handles the display of the error object.

Comment: No. The console.error(error) shows the error, I know there is error in Permission of database, I think there is problem with bind function. But I am not able to find out!

Answer (score 0):

This basically happens because you are trying to render the value `this.state.error`. Since Firebase returns a promise as an error, render function has no idea how to render it. So this error should appear.

To overcome this, you can use `this.state.error.toString()` instead to render it.

**Edit**

If you think this is a bind issue as you said in the comments, you can use arrow functions instead to to bind the `saveDatabase` function.

```
saveDatabase = (userID) =>{
 firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
 email: this.state.email,
 password: this.state.password
 }, function(error) {
   if (error) {
      console.warn(error);
      this.setState({
        error : error,
        isLoading: false
      })
   }
   else {
     Actions.main_home()
   }
 });
}
```

But if you have already bind the function when it is being called, this is not necessary.